# How to test routes' middleware?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

Let's say I have a group of routes which are protected by a middleware:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'verified'], function () {
    Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');
    Route::get('/settings', 'SettingsController@show')->name('settings.show');
});
```

How can I test that these routes are protected by `verified` middleware? If I write those tests, are they considered as feature tests or unit tests?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409343/unit-test-laravel-middleware

Comment: Also, if you're simply testing the functionality of the middleware class, it's unit testing. If you're testing if nothing breaks when you apply it to a route and make a request to the said route, it's feature testing.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but i think your task is to test your code and let Laravel's developers to test its core. If there are no errors, this mean it should work as excepted. Otherwise you could write tests for entire framework.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Is there anything you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware testing highly depends on the logic of the middleware itself and on the possible outcomes. Let's take the `verified` middleware you cited as an example:

We expect the user to be redirected (302) to the "Verify your email" page if it has not verified his email (the `email_verified_at` attribute is null), otherwise we expect a normal response (200).

How can we simulate a user accessing our page? With the `actingAs` method. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication):

> The `actingAs` helper method provides a simple way to authenticate a given user as the current user.

So our code will look something like this:

```php
use App\User;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testAccessWithoutVerification()
    {
        // Create a dummy user
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        // Try to access the page
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                         ->get('/the-page-we-want-to-test');

        // Assert the expected response status
        $response->assertStatus(302);
    }

    public function testAccessWithVerification()
    {
        // Create a dummy user, but this time we set the email_verified_at
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email_verified_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        ]);

        // Try to access the page
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                         ->get('/the-page-we-want-to-test');

        // Assert the expected response status
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

}
```

The docs have an [entire page dedicated to HTTP tests](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests), check it out.